readability with always_specify_types
I have set always_specify_types in analysis_options.yaml as it forces me to make sure of the field types being used which otherwise I would overlook. Trying to implement clean architecture, the types being visible also help applying CA principles.
However, as presently set with  always_specify_types, once specified the types correspond to a lot more characters which look exactly the same as the rest of the code. This makes it harder to focus on the code itself.
If the type is not explicitly written then it is suggested in what appears to be smaller and/or narrower fonts within in a contrast box. It is actually nice and makes a readable code, but then it clutters the problems section with "Missing type annotation" warning and underlines the variable name with a squiggly line, hence corresponding to 2 distractions from reading the code.
Is there a way with always_specify_types for the user

to implement a font (or font size or font style) for the type specification, that is different from the font (font size and font style) for the proper code, without having the squiggly underlines and warnings ?
to validate the suggested type while keeping its formatting and lifting both the squiggly underlines and warnings ?

